# How to prevent 'form resubmit' after redirect in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, google-chrome

I'm having an issue where I submit a form successfully. It redirects to the show action. If I refresh the page (ctrl+r) it opens a prompt asking if I want to 'Confirm Form Resubmit', which I don't want to do.

Has anyone seen this problem before and know how to fix it?

Here's some code:

The form view:

```
= simple_form_for @book_request do |f|
  = f.input :title
  .actions= f.submit
```

The show view

```
%dl
  %dt Title
  %dd= @book_request.title
```

My controller:

```
...

respond_to :html

def show
  respond_with(@book_request = BookRequest.find(params[:id]))
end

def new
  respond_with(@book_request = BookRequest.new)
end

def create
  @book_request = BookRequest.new(params[:book_request])
  @book_request.save
  respond_with(@book_request)
end

def edit
  respond_with(@book_request = BookRequest.find(params[:id]))
end

def update
  @book_request = BookRequest.find(params[:id])
  @book_request.update_attributes(params[:book_request])
  respond_with(@book_request)
end

...
```

Update:

This issue looks like it has been resolved. I just updated to chrome Version 26.0.1410.43 and it works as expected.

Comment: So I tried it in Firefox (I'm using Chrome) and it works as expected (no prompt), maybe this is a bug in Chrome.

Comment: The point of the redirect after a form submit is to avoid this problem. This really shouldn't be happening, I think there's more at play here. Got some code?

Comment: Are you sure you're redirecting to the show action rather than just invoking it as part of the same request/response cycle?

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. It's a simple form, when I submit and goes to the create/update action it saves the object successfully, and redirects correctly. I'm using respond_with in my actions (`respond_with @object`).

Comment: @qqx, it does the redirect (I get redirected to the show page). What do you mean 'same request/response cycle', would this be like if the form was submitted and there were errors and you tried to submit again?

Comment: My meaning of "request/response" cycle was the handling of a single browser request, rather than responding to one request with a redirect response than handling another browser request to actually execute the `show` action. Just because you're seeing the content expected from the `show` action does **not** mean that you're being redirected to that. It's almost certain that your form handler is doing the rendering itself rather than sending a redirect. Please edit your question to show the code that you think sends a redirect response to the browser.

Comment: Ok added some code as an example. I should note that this happens on all of my forms that get redirected to their show page. So far this happens only in Chrome. Both Firefox and Safari work as expected (no form resubmit prompts).

Comment: In my chrome inspect for the network analysis I get the following order of requests/responses: /book_request POST 302 _Found_, /book_request/23 GET 200 _OK_, followed by the asset GET requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug in chrome. Should be fixed soon.
For more info see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177855

Edit: If you want temporary fix (for development purposes) you can just add any get parameter to the for submission url. After handling POST, redirect as usual.

```
= simple_form_for @book_request, url: books_url(time: DateTime.now) do |f|
  = f.input :title
  .actions= f.submit
```

Comment: Thanks for finding this, kind of figured it was a chrome issue since it worked as expected in other browsers.